# Progress bar freezes during Drupal installation

Tags: 8, installation

When I install Drupal 8via composer on Centos7 with php7 the Progress installation bar does not budge unless I refresh the browser (Tried Chrome, opera and Firefox)but it does not install properly. I can install Drupal 7 via composer with no problems. Any suggestions please?[image]

Comment: I once had this there it was a Chrome issue :/

Comment: And the Drupal did run in a quite custom Debian Docker :/

Comment: You could try installation via drush, assuming you have access to server and can install drush. That may reveal more information about any failures, and rule out browser issues that leymanxx points out.